# Is it possible to access Java constructor by creating 1 object instead multiple object

Tags: java, constructor, constructor-overloading

Let me explain what I'm trying to achieve in this constructor. As you can see I have 3 Constructor and to get the output of each constructor I have to create 3 Objects. Is it possible to get the 3 outputs by only creating 1 object instead of creating 3 objects to get the output of all 3 constructors? If it's not possible mind someone explaining why it is not or if it's possible then show me how can it be done. Thanks

```
public class Op{ 

public Op(String a){ 
    System.out.println("Default"); 
} 

public Op(String a, int b){ 
    System.out.println("String and Int"); 
} 

public Op(String a, String c, int b){ 
    System.out.println("String, String & Int");
}


public static void main(String args[]){ 
Op d1 = new Op("lol"); 
Op d2 = new Op("Hi",21); 
Op d3 = new Op("Bye","Cube",47);
}
```

}

Comment: Is this with or without modifying the constructors?

Comment: It is not unusual with a constructor with fewer arguments calling one with more arguments where some values are set to some default value

Comment: You could fiddle around with the `Unsafe` class which is highly discouraged, though

Comment: Is it possible without modifying the constructors? @GBlodgett

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke constructors into other constructors using `this(...)`

```
public class Op {
    public Op(String a) {
        System.out.println("Default");
    }

    public Op(String a, int b) {
        this(a);
        System.out.println("String and Int");
    }

    public Op(String a, String c, int b) {
        this(a, b);
        System.out.println("String, String & Int");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Op d3 = new Op("Bye", "Cube", 47);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Default
String and Int
String, String & Int
```

You could also do it the other way around, and you can also invoke a `super(...)` constructor invoking one of the constructors of a super class

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor chaining..
 public class Op {

```
public Op(String a) {
    System.out.println("Default");
}

public Op(String a, int b) {
    this(a);
    System.out.println("String and Int");
}

public Op(String a, String c, int b) {
    this(a, b);
    System.out.println("String, String & Int");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Op d3 = new Op("Bye", "Cube", 47);
}
```

}